# Flutter Transform.rotate is working very laggy for Compass events and not smooth so how to make it smooth

Tags: flutter, smoothing, compass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD1Fn.png)

Flutter Transform.rotate is working very laggy for Compass events and not smooth so how to make it smooth because it is not moving smoothly its jummping so how to achieve it Flutter Qibla.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to achieve smooth compass rotation in flutter is to use smooth compass flutter package **this may help someone**
https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_compass_new

**For Qibla direction**

```
SmoothCompass(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  isQiblahCompass: true,
  compassBuilder: (context,snapshot,child){
    return  AnimatedRotation(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds:800),
      turns: snapshot?.data?.turns??0,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child:Image.asset("assets/images/compass.png",fit: BoxFit.fill,),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child:AnimatedRotation(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              turns: (snapshot?.data?.qiblahOffset??0)/360,
              //Place your qiblah needle here
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,),
                child: const VerticalDivider(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  thickness: 5,),
              )
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
)
```